# Alternating exponential distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Consider a process where objects arrive according to an exponential distribution with $rate=\lambda$.  Let $X$ be the number that arrive over an interval of length $T$. Then the number that arrive is distributed according to a Poisson distribution (a) and conditional on that number the arrivals are uniformly distributed over the interval (b).

Now consider an alternating process where the i'th object arrives according to $Exponential(\lambda)$ if $i$ is even and $Exponential(\mu)$ if $i$ is odd.  Is there a nice description of this process? Do either of the above properties (a,b) generalize?

Comment: If it helps, you can describe it as a continuous time Markov chain on state space $\mathbb{N}$ with jump rates $q(2n-1,2n)=\lambda$ and $q(2n, 2n+1)=\mu$, so a pure birth process.  Then $X=X_T$ is the state of the chain at time $T$, and the distribution of number of arrivals by time $t$ is the transition probability $P(X=k)=p_T(0, k)$.

Comment: What you describe is an "alternating renewal process". A quick look into the books of S. M. Ross, Introduction to Probability Models or Asmussen,may help.

Comment: @DieterKadelka thanks, I'd forgotten the name! However, the solution requires lots of complicated integrals (which wolfram alpha couldn't solve) so it's not clear whether these properties hold.